# Please undelete or prevent deletion of questions with helpful, treasured comments

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

First, I declare my naïveté in linguistics, which (I readily admit) might affect the writing quality of my questions. However, I've been self-learning linguistics; my love of etymology inspirits me to read the books recommended [herein](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/901/5306) and [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/34f40g/introductory_book_on_historical_linguistics_for/?ref=share&ref_source=link).
   I hereby permit any benefactor to edit my posts (no need to ask me first).

Please beware that downvotes wound many others, and not only me; I request the following for commenters' (and NOT only my) sake. In comments under the questions below, many commenters have volunteered helpful  advice and insight into my questions. Because even just 1 downvote can induce deletion, whenever one downvotes my question, one perforce causes the deletion, removal, and banishment of all these priceless comments that can help so many readers. So:

1. downvoters of my questions: I implore you please to cease downvoting, and to help me improve my questions instead. I hope that your intent is not to ail or torment the commenters and anyone who benefits from these questions.

2. others who didn't downvote my questions: would you please consider upvoting simply to cancel or neutralise the downvotes and their noxious consequences? Thank you effusively.

---

Would the following please be undeleted? Questions downvoted without sound explanation, but with helpful comments, in increasing temporal order:

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/how-does-the-subjunctive-under-join
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12269/how-to-classify-and-differentiate-emic-units
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12196/evolution-of-proto-germanic-pleg-pledge-and-plight
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12197/how-did-the-pie-root-tere-evolve-into-threshold
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/how-did-the-pie-root-sag-evolve-into-hegemony
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12440/how-does-the-prefix-in-function-in-impart
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11743/unpaired-word-in-one-language-but-paired-in-another
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12478/did-the-latin-rogamentum-truly-fall-from-favour-why
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12528/how-can-you-interpret-or-unravel-common-homonyms-more-efficiently
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12622/how-does-to-quench-relate-to-pie-steig-to-prick-stick-pierce

Comment: You know that canvassing for votes is just as likely to get you downvotes as upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

To add to what user6726 wrote, [here is the Stackexchange policy on comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). The relevant message to take away from there is that comments are for transient information. It's helpful to act as if they are going to be deleted someday.

If you learnt enough from the comments to answer your own question, by all means, do so. If the comments already contained all the information you were looking for, you can acknowledge them and write an answer yourself, like I have done for "[Term for the modified part of a prepositional complement](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/term-for-the-modified-part-of-a-prepositional-complement/9023)".

> I hope that your intent is not to ail or torment the commenters and anyone who benefits from these questions.

Don't worry about tormentors, Stackexchange fixes that automatically. ([What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting))

> others who didn't downvote my questions: would you please consider upvoting simply to cancel or neutralise the downvotes and their noxious consequences?

[Ideally, voting should be used for something else.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) Moreover, I think you got all those "-1"s automatically, because the questions were closed.

---

If you prefer, there is already [a fairly active forum for discussing etymology at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology).

Comment: Closing questions doesn't give any automatic downvotes. The only action I know of that does that is flagging as spam or abuse.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see an actual question here. Recall that SE sites are by designed for giving specific answers to specific questions, and not for general discussion (there are fora out there designed for open-ended discussion).

Perhaps you can generate a question that is about this subject matter, but I don't think this is the appropriate place such such a question. The question that you *could* pose is whether it is can be *required* that a comment be added in order to down-vote a question or answer. Since voting to close a question requires a specific reason, conceivably one could make a similar requirement for downvoting. This topic should be taken up on the SE Meta site. Otherwise, I don't see that there is anything that is answerable here.

Comment: I edited my OP just now, but I originally did ask 'would you please consider upvoting simply to cancel or neutralise the downvotes and their noxious consequences?'. I added another: Would the following please be undeleted?

Comment: It's not clear that you understood what I said. A question is a request for information, and a request is a request for action. Making a request in the syntactic form of an interrogative does not make a request into a question. So, what is your *question*?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Yes, you are right; I didn't comprehend the nuance. I'll cogitate this some more. If I understand your answer correctly, then my OP is more of a request than a question. However, requests are allowed here, no?

Comment: I don't know if special pleading is consistent with the purpose of the meta site(s). On the face of it, I would say no, since Meta as I understand it is about understanding how SE works, and the present "question" is off-topic in that sense.

Comment: @user6726 At Meta, we don't need to be that strict about the Q&A format. According to http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta, discussions are allowed here.